# What online resources are available for identifying songs from audio or score?

Tags: reference-request

**`Spread across various questions and answers on Music Fans SE are mentions of tools to help identify songs given audio or an excerpt from a score. This question/answer(s) attempt to compile them in one place for easy reference. Please add your favorite(s) to the answers.`**

What online resources are available to (help) identify music for which I have at least some audio (or can hum/sing) or part of a written score (or can notate)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### I have audio available (recorded or I can sing/play it)

- [Musipedia](https://www.musipedia.org/) (hum, enter notation, or enter pitch "contour" [i.e., up, down, repeat])

> A searchable, editable, and expandable collection of tunes, melodies, and musical themes. (Musipedia)

- [Shazam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shazam_(application)) (uses 10-second clip of song)

> The application can identify music, movies, advertising, and television shows, based on a short sample played and using the microphone on the device. (Wikipedia)

- SoundHound (Hum, sing, or play recording; 10 second clip)
- [Bing Audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_Audio) (continuous listening, no clip time-limit)

> Bing Audio (also known as Bing Music) is a music recognition application ... designed to recognize recorded songs, not live performances or humming. (Wikipedia)

- [AHA Music](https://www.aha-music.com/) (website and browser extension) (Chinese music/artists only?)
- [Midomi](https://www.midomi.com/) (Hum, sing, or play recording; 10 seconds or more; also has text-based searching)

---

### I have written notation available (or I can create it)

- [Musipedia](https://www.musipedia.org/) (hum, enter notation, or enter pitch "contour" [i.e., up, down, repeat])

> A searchable, editable, and expandable collection of tunes, melodies, and musical themes. (Musipedia)

- [Peachnote](https://www.peachnote.com) (a.k.a [IMSLP Sheet Music Search Tool](http://www.peachnote.com/#!site=imslp.org&nt=singleNoteAffine&npq=*))

---

### Music Fans questions/answers addressing this issue

- [Methods for identifying a tune online](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8048/methods-for-identifying-a-tune-online/8049#8049)
- [What is the easy way to identify the soundtrack from any Hollywood movie?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/what-is-the-easy-way-to-identify-the-soundtrack-from-any-hollywood-movie)
- [Is there a music score search engine?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10519/is-there-a-music-score-search-engine)
- [Piano arrangement identification from one measure of sheet music](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/piano-arrangement-identification-from-one-measure-of-sheet-music)